# Monitor certain webpage load times (including all images, css, etc..) using PHP

Tags: php, monitoring

This is a very broad question, so I'm just looking for the best way of doing this.

I want to periodically monitor certain pages on my website.

I am looking to write a PHP script which will load the page as if it is being loaded in a browser. So that means, it loads all *CSS, Javascript, Images, Videos, etc..*.

I want to just get the load time of these pages and then email the results to myself in a `crontab`. For this I was going to use `microtime()` and a `phpMailer`.

Does anyone know of a script to load a complete page, or have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: I can imagine what you are trying to do, but remember CSS and javascript may import own resources. Also do you want to fetch the results asynchronous, or not? Testing a websites performance is highly inaccurate this way.

Comment: @KingCrunch Honestly, I open to any and all solutions. Im just looking to test the performance of certain pages on a website. I wanted to put a script in a cron job, and if the time to load reaches a certain point, I would be alerted via email. Any suggestions on how to do this would be great :)

Comment: I would agree.  Especially if the php script is being run on the webserver itself.  If most of your content is being pulled locally, the results would be very unrealistic.

Comment: Do you not have access to the web server logs?

Comment: @tubaguy50035 I do, but I don't have the time to sit there and read through them all the time. I need to be alerted when the load time is slow.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that.  You could always build a script that looks through the logs and finds load times for you, emails when they're slow.

Comment: @mlishn, maybe you are looking for a website monitoring tool? There are plenty of those that are available online and send you notifications if site goes down. But they just ping your page, don't load everything.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Right, but wouldnt parsing an entire log file every (for example) 5 minutes be very slow, unless I delete the log at the end of the script (which isn't ideal). Also which log tracks specific urls in apache??

Comment: You could use a log rotator like cronolog.  Or you could get super cool and pipe your apache log output to a php script that does nothing else but watch for high load times and then emails.

Comment: @Tim I will be using those, but I wanted to see if I could have my own as well.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 that sounds cool, ill look into it

Comment: Just make sure your script doesn't get too heavy.  I could be totally wrong on this, but I think the worker gets hung up until the log write is successful.  So if your script takes a couple seconds to send an email, that worker may be unavailable during that time.

Answer (score 1):

What if the page has dynamic content? You will also need to execute all the JavaScript and fetch all CSS images to get the final amount of time. I believe that is impossible using only PHP.

Answer (score 1):

A php script you run from the same server you host your site will give you abnormal readings (very low) since it's loading on the first hop essentially. What you really would want to do is run a script from various servers outside of your own. There are also limitations with what php can see ie JS and JQuery etc.

The simplest is to check from your home pc, using **[jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)**.  You set your home browser to use it as a proxy and go to whichever website you want. Jmeter will record statistics. When you are happy you can choose to save the stats.

This avoids the problems of handling JS and JQuery through a script.

Comment: JMeter can also be launched in console, which means that it can be run from PHP script :)

Comment: @Tim cool. I've never tried it though but its great to know that it has that functionality as well.

Answer (score 0):

This could get very complicated. You'd basically have to parse the HTML, and then there's tons of edge cases, like JS including resources, etc... I would definitely recommend using something like the network tab of Chrome's dev tools instead.